# Avoid 0 and others to count as False

Tags: python

In Python, there are several values that count as `False`:

```
>>> if False or None or 0 or 0.0 or '' or [] or {} or set():
...   print 'True :)'
... else:
...   print 'False :('
... 
False :(
```

So, somewhere in my code I'm doing something like this:

```
    some_var = other_var or 'default' # Some default value
```

`other_var` could be `None` or any other value, if it's `None`, `some_var` should be filled with `'default'`.

But I kept having some troubles with this, so, debugging my code I found out that `other_var` sometimes was `0` (or any other value that counts as `False`), and `some_var` was filled with `'default'` instead of `0`.

So, is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying rather than doing this?

```
if other_var is None:
    some_var = 'default'
else:
    some_var = other_var
```

**No** is a valid answer.

Comment: You can use the `t if expr else f` syntax.

Comment: @Nate that still doesn't work (try it out with `other_var = 0`)

Comment: @julio.alegria whoops! totally misread your question. :^)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There *is* the [Conditional Expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (aka the "ternary operator") syntax:

```
some_var = 'default' if other_var is None else other_var
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Well I hope this is the best way, because I use this thing all the time and I don't want to have to change all my old code!

Comment: FYI this is roughly equivalent to C's `some_var = other_var ? other_var : default`